# How to query count(customer), count(order) pair

Tags: sql

Assuming we have tables

```
Order(customerId,orderDetails...) 
Customer(Id, customerDetails...)
```

What is the easiest way to query Count(customer)xCount(order) pair?

example

Customer:

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | Bob
2  | Ann
```

Order

```
CustomerId | Address
--------------------
 1         | Block1
 1         | Block2
 1         | Block1
 2         | Home Address
```

Want to get

```
CustomerCount | OrderCount
--------------------------
     1        |    3
     1        |    1
```

Comment: Isn't last row should be `2   |   1`?

Comment: No @Fahim Parkar, I want to get count of clients that did 1 order, not the id of client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
        SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) AS CustomerCount
               , COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
        FROM   Customer AS c
               INNER JOIN [Order] AS o ON o.customerID = c.ID
        GROUP BY
              c.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1442)

**Edit**

Coming to think of it, the previous statement can be reduced to this

```
        SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS CustomerCount
               , COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
        FROM   Customer AS c
               INNER JOIN [Order] AS o ON o.customerID = c.ID
        GROUP BY
              c.ID
```

but that gives me a nagging feeling that my initial statement is wrong to begin with

Comment: Nope, id doest seems to work, if 2 customers did the same amount of order it shows 2 lines

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - Can you adjust your testdata to show the error, I don't see it.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - I've adjusted the statement to what I *think* your requirements are.

Comment: Great, that is hat I was talking about, thanks a lot, bud doesn't SELECT distinct COUNT(c.CustomerID) AS CustomerCount, COUNT(*) AS OrderCount solve last issue?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - uh, yes, much simpler <g>. I'll adjust the answer

Comment: seems we can remove distinct COUNT(DISTINCT too, like here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2774d/2

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - I was about to write that but it made me think that the statement can be further reduced (see edit) what in turn made me think that it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select order.id, count(.CustomerId )
from Order order left join Customer customer on order.id = customer.CustomerId 
group by order.id
```